# React not rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I started using React in my app but I'm facing a problem, when going through some simple tutorials the examples do not work. When trying the example on JSFiddle it did work but whenever i try it on my own webapp nothing happens, I'm using Spring/Java on the backend if that matters.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Index</title>
        <!-- Add React -->
        <script th:src="@{/js/lib/react.js}"></script>
        <script th:src="@{/js/lib/react-dom.js}"></script>
        <script th:src="@{/js/lib/babel.js}"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="example"></div>

        <script type="text/babel" th:src="@{/js/testing.js}"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The Javascript

```
ReactDOM.render(<h1>Hello!</h1>, document.getElementById('example'));
```

Also the Network tab of Developer Tools doesn't show the 'testing.js' file
[image]

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your developer console? Is the javascript you show in your question supposed to be in the `testing.js` file?

Comment: Not as the code is right now, BUT when i remove the `type='text/babel'` attribute,  then the `testing.js` file is shown in the network tab and displays this error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`

Comment: which build of babel.js do you have? Are you sure you have the version intended for use in the browser?

Comment: It's Babel Standalone 6.24.1

Comment: when you inspect the generated html in the browser, what does the `text/babel` script tag look like?

Comment: `<script type="text/babel" src="/js/testing.js"></script>`

Comment: does it work if you inline the JS rather than loading it from an external file?

Comment: No, it's the same, no errors. (Except when removing the type attribute)

Comment: Odd. If you were getting errors, I would expect that you were experiencing this problem with babel: https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/340 but that would manifest as a console error. Can you confirm that the babel.js that's getting served is actually what you expect it to be?

Comment: I switched to babel-core and it is working, except that I had to use version 5.* since 6 is giving this error `Cannot read property 'keys' of undefined`. Thank you for your help.